# Merge list of map using Enum.find_value

Tags: elixir

For merging  lists based on id

```
products =
  [
    %{id: 7, name: "A", count: 1},
    %{id: 8, name: "B", count: 1},
    %{name: "C", count: 0}
  ]

price =
  [
    %{price: "$10.00", p_id: 7},
    %{price: "$29.95", p_id: 10},
  ]
```

currently using

```
Enum.map(products, &Map.put(&1, :price, Enum.find(price, fn %{p_id: pid} -> pid == &1.id end).price))
```

But it raises an error if `id` is not present in the list of products.

```
(KeyError) key :id not found in: %{count: 1, name: "A"}
```

How to use `Enum.find_value` for the same?

Comment: What is `products`? What list `id` is not presented in? Raises what? [`Enum.find_value/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#find_value/3) won’t help here in any case.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Sorry my bad ```products = [
  %{ name: "A", count: 1},
  %{id: 8, name: "B", count: 1},
  %{id: 9, name: "C", count: 0}
]``` and ```price = [
  %{price: "$14.95", p_id: 8},
  %{price: "$10.00", p_id: 7},
  %{price: "$29.95", p_id: 10},
  %{price: "$1.00", p_id: 9}

]``` . If `id` is not present in `products` the it throws `(KeyError) key :id not found in: %{count: 1, name: "A"}` error. I hope it makes sense. So was thinking of the way to use Enum.find_value so that it return value of `id` if found.

Comment: I have updated the question and the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the former list is referred later as `product`, the `latter` as `price` and the issue occurs when the latter has no element with `p_id` corresponding to one of elements in the former one, one might go with

```rb
product =
  [
    %{id: 7, name: "A", count: 1},
    %{id: 8, name: "B", count: 1},
    %{id: 9, name: "C", count: 0}
  ]
price =
  [
    %{price: "$14.95", p_id: 8},
    %{price: "$10.00", p_id: 7}
  ]
```

In that case, `Enum.map/2` would raise, but not on `Enum.find/2` which is happily returning `nil` when no element can be found, but on a) inner function clause pattern match and b) on `.price` access when `Enum.find/2` returns `nil`.

The nasty solution would be to eliminate both issues using [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html?) instead of dot notation:

```rb
Enum.map(
  products,
  &Map.put(
    &1,
    :price,
    #                        ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓              ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
    Enum.find(price, fn p -> p[:p_id] == &1.id end)[:price]
  )
)
```

Another way round would be to properly lookup the element and deal with it accordingly

```rb
Enum.map(
  products, fn %{id: id} = product ->
    product_price =
      price
      |> Enum.find(&match?(%{p_id: ^id}, &1))
      |> case do
        %{price: price} -> price
        _ -> nil
      end
    Map.put(product, :price, product_price)
  end)
```

---

OTOH, if `id` is not present in `product`, it raises `KeyError` because of `&1.id` call. to avoid this one might use the latter code and add the explicit sink-all clause to handle this. This version is the best in terms of robustness and being error-prone:

```rb
Enum.map(
  products, fn
    %{id: id} = product ->
      product_price =
        price
        |> Enum.find(&match?(%{p_id: ^id}, &1))
        |> case do
          %{price: price} -> price
          _ -> nil # no price presented
        end
      Map.put(product, :price, product_price)

    product -> product # no id presented
  end)
#⇒ [
#    %{count: 1, id: 7, name: "A", price: "$10.00"},
#    %{count: 1, id: 8, name: "B", price: nil},
#    %{count: 0, name: "C"}
#  ]
```